# Remove Value From Public Enum

Tags: c#, .net, enums, fedex

I am attempting to remove a value from a `public enum` in my project.  The issue that I have is that anytime I remove the value I get an error of

> There is an error in XML document (1,2909)

What is it with this code that prevents me from removing an element?

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1586.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http:Site")]
public enum TDOTT {

    /// <remarks/>
    AD,        
    /// <remarks/>
    AP,
    /// <remarks/>
    AT,
    /// <remarks/>
    AT1,
    /// <remarks/>
    AD1,
    /// <remarks/>
    ED,
    /// <remarks/>
    EP,
    /// <remarks/>
    SP,
}
```

If further code is needed, please let me know and I'll be happy to provide.

**EDIT**
This is what it looks like when an element is removed (I am manually removing)

```
public enum TDOTT {

    /// <remarks/>
    AD,        
    /// <remarks/>
    AP,
    /// <remarks/>
    AT,
    /// <remarks/>
    AT1,
    /// <remarks/>
    AD1,
    /// <remarks/>
    ED,
    /// <remarks/>
    EP,
}
```

And this is how it is called using C#

```
foreach (TDOTT ts in td.DOT)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ts.T, ts.D);                                      
}
```

**EDIT 2**
This is further C# syntax, and a comment above the line that produces the error

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> tempList = new List<string> { "666288603319" };

        try
        {
            foreach (var trackingNumber in tempList)
            {
                TrackRequest request = CreateTrackRequest(trackingNumber);
                TrackService service = new TrackService();
                //The below line is hit and error is thrown
                TrackReply reply = service.track(request);
            }
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerText);
        }
    }
    private static TrackRequest CreateTrackRequest(string trackingNumber)
    {
        TrackRequest request = new TrackRequest();

        request.WebAuthenticationDetail = new WebAuthenticationDetail();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential = new WebAuthenticationCredential();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Key = usercredentialKEY;
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.UserCredential.Password = usercredentialPassword;
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential = new WebAuthenticationCredential();
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential.Key = parentcredentialKEY;
        request.WebAuthenticationDetail.ParentCredential.Password = parentcredentialPassword;

        request.ClientDetail = new ClientDetail();
        request.ClientDetail.AccountNumber = AccountNumber;
        request.ClientDetail.MeterNumber = MeterNumber;

        request.TransactionDetail = new TransactionDetail();
        request.TransactionDetail.CustomerTransactionId = "any value";  //This is a reference field for the customer.  Any value can be used and will be provided in the response.

        request.Version = new VersionId();

        request.SelectionDetails = new TrackSelectionDetail[1] { new TrackSelectionDetail() };
        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier = new TrackPackageIdentifier();
        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier.Value = trackingNumber;

        request.SelectionDetails[0].PackageIdentifier.Type = TrackIdentifierType.TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG;
        request.SelectionDetails[0].ShipDateRangeBeginSpecified = false;
        request.SelectionDetails[0].ShipDateRangeEndSpecified = false;

        request.ProcessingOptions = new TrackRequestProcessingOptionType[1] { new TrackRequestProcessingOptionType() };
        request.ProcessingOptions[0] = TrackRequestProcessingOptionType.INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS;

        return request;
    }
```

**EDIT 3**
This is the `TrackRequest` Class synatx

```
    public partial class TrackRequest {

    private WebAuthenticationDetail webAuthenticationDetailField;

    private ClientDetail clientDetailField;

    private TransactionDetail transactionDetailField;

    private VersionId versionField;

    private TrackSelectionDetail[] selectionDetailsField;

    private string transactionTimeOutValueInMillisecondsField;

    private TrackRequestProcessingOptionType[] processingOptionsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public WebAuthenticationDetail WebAuthenticationDetail {
        get {
            return this.webAuthenticationDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.webAuthenticationDetailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ClientDetail ClientDetail {
        get {
            return this.clientDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.clientDetailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public TransactionDetail TransactionDetail {
        get {
            return this.transactionDetailField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionDetailField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public VersionId Version {
        get {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SelectionDetails")]
    public TrackSelectionDetail[] SelectionDetails {
        get {
            return this.selectionDetailsField;
        }
        set {
            this.selectionDetailsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="nonNegativeInteger")]
    public string TransactionTimeOutValueInMilliseconds {
        get {
            return this.transactionTimeOutValueInMillisecondsField;
        }
        set {
            this.transactionTimeOutValueInMillisecondsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProcessingOptions")]
    public TrackRequestProcessingOptionType[] ProcessingOptions {
        get {
            return this.processingOptionsField;
        }
        set {
            this.processingOptionsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include an example of the code that does the removing.

Comment: @Soviut - I am manually removing the element(s) as I do not want to see that data on the Console but I get the XML error above anytime I remove.  See edit.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Will you comment to inform me of what the issue with my ? is?

Comment: Provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NineBerry - see my edit.  Please let me know if the additional C# syntax will allow someone to assist.

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize and enumeration.   When you serialize a class only public properties are output in xml.  So if you don't want to output some properties in a class make them private.

Comment: What is the class TrackRequest? Where is its definition and the definition track()?

Comment: @o_weisman - just made an edit to show the TrackRequest class.  Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @jdweng - if I alter the synatx to be private enum TDOTT - I get multiple errors about being inaccessible due to protection level

Comment: Put the enum outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this question is truly about the `FedEx` Developers API then I am going to make the assumption that your `public enum TDOTT` is actually (pulling this straight from the FedEx API Documentation)

```
    public enum TrackingDateOrTimestampType {

    /// <remarks/>
    ACTUAL_DELIVERY,        
    /// <remarks/>
    ACTUAL_PICKUP,
    /// <remarks/>
    ACTUAL_TENDER,
    /// <remarks/>
    ANTICIPATED_TENDER,
    /// <remarks/>
    APPOINTMENT_DELIVERY,
    /// <remarks/>
    ESTIMATED_DELIVERY,
    /// <remarks/>
    ESTIMATED_PICKUP,
    /// <remarks/>
    SHIP,
}
```

Now on the same assumption, based off your code posted you want to exclude `SP` which appears to be the equivalent of `SHIP`

Going off the above assumptions, if you would have posted the syntax that comes after your line throwing the error, it would look something like the below (I say something due to the fact that I have modified mine to suit my needs, but this will get across the general idea)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Pulled this from the example you gave
    List<string> tempList = new List<string> { "666288603319" };
        foreach (var trackingNumber in tempList)
        {
            TrackRequest request = CreateTrackRequest(trackingNumber);
            TrackService service = new TrackService();
            TrackReply reply = service.track(request);

            //Now here is where my syntax is set-up that should closely mirror what the FedEx API shows straight from the .zip
            if (reply.HighestSeverity == NotificationSeverityType.SUCCESS || reply.HighestSeverity == NotificationSeverityType.NOTE || reply.HighestSeverity == NotificationSeverityType.WARNING)
                foreach (CompletedTrackDetail completedTrackDetail in reply.CompletedTrackDetails)
                    foreach (TrackDetail trackDetail in completedTrackDetail.TrackDetails)
                        if (trackDetail.DatesOrTimes != null)
                        {
                            foreach (TrackingDateOrTimestamp timestamp in trackDetail.DatesOrTimes)
                                //if my assumption is accurate and you want to exclude ship add this
                                if (Convert.ToString(timestamp.Type) != "SHIP")
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", timestamp.Type, timestamp.DateOrTimestamp); 
                        }
```

Now look at the comments that I added in, instead of attempting to modify a `public enum` that could be tied to multiply places inside the syntax that would all need to be altered, which is above your coding experience, I would recommend to modify it as I display above simply by "filtering" based off the `timestamp.Type`

**For future reference** if you want to receive valid/helpful responses you need to include accurate syntax.  It is okay to alter the syntax if it is sensitive or personal information (such as giving XXX for a Tracking Number), but altering the `public enum` when the FedEx API source code is freely downloadable, was just silly.  I only rarely peruse these forums, but since recently I was ready to shave my head after learning the FedEx API - I thought I would chime in on this.

If any of my assumptions are incorrect, please modify your original post with the **ACCURATE** code from the FedEx API and I will be able to assist (as well as I am sure many others).